# Order of Dictionary.Keys.ToArray() vs Dictionary.Values.ToArray()

Tags: c#, dictionary, implementation, processing-efficiency

I have a question regarding implementation details of Dictionary

Assume the following code:

```
private IDictionary<Int64, Int32> _data = new Dictionary<Int64, Int32>();

private void Foo() 
{
    Int64[] keys = _data.Keys.ToArray<Int64>();
    Int32[] vals = _data.Values.ToArray<Int32>();

    // Further code goes here
}
```

May I assume at this point, that

```
_dict[keys[i]] == vals[i]
```

for each `i in [0 .. _data.Length-1]`, or might the order of both arrays be unrelated?

Comment: Event if you could prove it's true now, you probably can't assume that it will be true tomorrow (or when new version of .NET is released).

Comment: Agree with Marcin. Also Why do you need this?

Comment: I am writing my own serialization routine and require to sort these arrays. I am restricted to use a Dictionary over a SortedList, etc

Comment: Why do you have to break the dictionary out to two separate arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
private void Foo() 
{
    Int64[] keys = _data.Keys.ToArray<Int64>();
    Int32[] vals = _data.Keys.Select(k => _data[k]).ToArray<Int32>();

    // Further code goes here
}
```

It's still O(n) time and it won't break if .NET changes in the future.